# Clear the Listview before reloading on Refresh

Tags: java, android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a listview where I populate it from JSON. I have applied Swiperefresh layout to clear and refill the listview again.

But My problem is Instead of clearing old items, It then adds new value at bottom of old ones. But I want to completely clear everything and then add new value from start.

Here is my code

```html
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {

                                             mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                             mExampleList.clear();
                                             mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                             parseJSON();
                                         }
                                     }
            );


        }
    }


    private void parseJSON() {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String videoTitle = hit.getString("title");
                                String link = hit.getString("link");
                           //     String notes = hit.getString("notes");
                          //      String question = hit.getString("question");
//                                String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
//                                int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(videoTitle,link));
                                mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Show your `mSwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your below code

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {

                                             mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                             mExampleList.clear();
                                             mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                             parseJSON();
                                         }
                                     }
            );
```

to

```
updateListContent();
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               updateListContent();
            }
        });
    }
```

Create a method to update the data to the list:

```
   public void updateListContent() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    if(mExampleList != null)
      mExampleList.clear();
     parseJSON();
    }
```

Comment: now it is only loading and no list is showing . Earlier list was shown only when if I refresh new data will append itself at bottom..Now not the list is loading and progress bar is loading infinitely.

Comment: I thought you were setting the data before this code. I have updated the answer. That should work for you.